# VirtualBox without X server

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtualization

I want to run a guest operating system under a Linux host with VirtualBox, but I don't want to run from within X. I *don't* want a headless configuration, I *don't* want to run VirtualBox in the background, I *don't* want any remote protocols. I just want the guest OS to take control of my console (keyboard, mouse and monitor) and render to the framebuffer directly, not from within an X window.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can set things up to auto login, run X with no window manager, and launch Virtual box full screen, this may have the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Can you give some feed back of what you are trying to do? (non technical, customer perspective, goal directed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's currently not possible. It would be theoretically possible to port VirualBox to some other graphical backend, like the raw framebuffer. The reason for this not being done is probably that X is the only graphical solution for Linux with good acceleration support. But hopefully VirtualBox will be able to run under Wayland in the near future.